# On this code from Codecademy, why does the $ sign disappear on the line $apple->type = "apple"; and what does the -> mean here?

Tags: php

```
class Fruit { public $count = 3; public $type; }

$apple = new Fruit(); 
$apple->type = "apple"; 
print $apple->count; // 3 print 
$apple->type; // apple
```

Comment: You're looking at object oriented programming.

Comment: ever heard of `$this` ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php